# Gradle tasks.build.doLast() not being invoked

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to perform some file copying after a build has been performed and found some answers saying tasks.build.doLast() can be used.
However if I add this to my (or to any gradle) script, then its not being invoked.

Does it have to be invoked explicity, if so how?

```
tasks.build.doLast(){
    println '********************* LAST ******************'
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the absence of Gradle version information I will assume you are using the latest and pull from the current documentation. Your current code looks a little off with the `doLast()` dot notation.

If you were writing a task to print a line, the code below will work:

```
task1 {

    //Task configuration goes here.

    doLast {
        println "********************* LAST ******************"
    }
}
```

If you are using `doLast` to finalize another task Gradle has a method for doing that. You can use `finalizedBy`. Below is an example:

```
task1 {
        println "Task 1 successful"
}

task2 {

        println "********************* LAST ******************"
}    

task1.finalizedBy task2
```

For more information on Gradle Tasks you should check out [Chapter 14](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/tutorial_using_tasks.html) and [Chapter 17](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/more_about_tasks.html) of the Gradle documentation. There are examples of the different ways to define classes included in those short chapters.

Comment: I think this is wrong `task1.finalizedBy.task2`: there should be a space instead of the dot after `finalizedBy`, like this: `task1.finalizedBy task2`